# Randomly filtering points in unevenly distributed point dataset?

Tags: qgis, point, filter, heat-map, grids-graticules

I have a vegetation plots dataset which has unduly high concentrations of plots in certain parts of the dataset. I want to even out the concentrations of points so that there is a more even distribution of data geographically.

Can you point me to any previous questions that might have asked this question already or show me a process how I can use a grid and a point density map to filter the points to the desired maximum vegetation plots density (i.e. so many vegetation plots per sq km)?